# Why does python implementation use 9 times more memory than C?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, memory

I wrote a program to make a list of primes from 2 to a user given number in both python and C. I ran both the programs looking for primes up to the same number and looked at their respective processes in activity monitor. I found that the python implementation used exactly 9 times as much memory as the C implementation. Why does python require so much more memory and why that specific multiple to store the same array of integers? Here are both implementations of the program:

Python version:

```
import math
import sys

top = int(input('Please enter the highest number you would like to have checked: '))
num = 3
prime_list = [2]
while num <= top:
    n = 0
    prime = True
    while int(prime_list[n]) <= math.sqrt(num):
        if num % prime_list[n] == 0:
            prime = False
            n = 0
            break
        n = n + 1
    if prime == True:
        prime_list.append(num)
        prime = False
    num = num + 1
print("I found ", len(prime_list), " primes")
print("The largest prime I found was ", prime_list[-1])
```

C version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    int N;
    int arraySize = 1;
    int *primes = malloc(100*sizeof(int));
    int isPrime = 1;
    primes[0] = 2;
    int timesRealloc = 0;
    int availableSlots = 100;

    printf("Please enter the largest number you want checked: \n");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    int j = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 3; i <= N; i+=2){
        j = 0;
        isPrime = 1;
        while (primes[j] <= sqrt(i)) {
            if (i%primes[j] == 0) {
                isPrime = 0;
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }
        if (isPrime == 1){
            primes[arraySize] = i;
            arraySize++;
        }
        if (availableSlots == arraySize){
            timesRealloc++;
            availableSlots += 100;
            primes = realloc(primes, availableSlots*sizeof(int));
        }
    }

    printf("I found %d primes\n", arraySize);
    printf("Memory was reallocated %d times\n", timesRealloc);
    printf("The largest prime I found was %d\n", primes[(arraySize-1)]);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First C uses assembly language to execute your program while Python uses an interpreter to execute some intermediate code. Second arrays in C are just memory areas while in Python they are (actually I'm nor sure) complex data structures. Third they may be dead dynamic objects not garbage-collected. Typically OO_languages with a rich type hierarchy and garbage collection use much more memory than C does.

Comment: Python does not have arrays, so it can not be "the same array". Also the int types in C and Python are very different.

Comment: @U.Windl yes, everything in CPython is a full-fledged object. List objects do use a primitive array of PyObject pointers underneath the hood, but there's a  lot more going on than a C primitive array.

Comment: Excellent research BTW!

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(123456)
28
```

That's *7* times the size of C `int`. In Python 3 integers are instances of `struct _longobject` a.k.a `PyLong`:

```
struct _longobject {
    PyVarObject ob_base;
    digit ob_digit[1];
};
```

where `PyVarObject` is

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject ob_base;
    Py_ssize_t ob_size;
} PyVarObject;
```

and `PyObject` is

```
typedef struct _object {
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    struct _typeobject *ob_type;
} PyObject;
```

From that we get the following memory usage for that object 123456 in 64-bit Python build:

- 8 bytes for reference counter (`Py_ssize_t`)
- 8 bytes for pointer to the type object `&PyLong_Type` (of type `PyTypeObject *`
- 8 bytes for counting the number of bytes in the variable-length part of the object;  (of type `Py_ssize_t`)
- 4 bytes for each 30 bits of digits in the integer.

Since 123456 fits in the first 30 bits, this sums up to 28, or `7 * sizeof (int)`

That in addition to the fact that each element in a Python `list` is a `PyObject *` which points the actual object; each of these pointers are 64 bits on 64-bit Python builds; which means that each list element reference alone consumes twice as much memory as a C `int`.

Add together 7 and 2 and you get **9**.

---

For more storage-efficient code you can use [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/array.html); with type code `'i'` the memory consumption should be quite close to the C version. `array`s have the [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.append) method thanks to which growing an array should be even easier than in C / with `realloc`.

Comment: OP could use [array module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/array.html) to reduce the memory use, trading for speed as the values are translated back and forth as accessed.